# iOS Programming:Correcting Text

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, autocorrect

So I've been developing an iOS application, and one part of it involves the user entering a paragraph of text, and I need my app to filter the text, and use Apple's autocorrect function, to rectify mistakes in the text. For example, if the text is-

The quick brown fox jumpet over the lazy dog

Then it should be able to take the word 'jumpet' and change it to jumped. Does anyone know how this can be done? And I don't have to prompt the user, I'm planning to run this code in a background thread, while an activity indicator spins.

Thanks A Lot!
Raghav

P.S. - The text is in an NSString...

Comment: Unless you disable it, autocorrection will be running as the user types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually check spelling in a string using [UITextChecker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextchecker_class/index.html).

I haven't used it myself but it looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank You! That's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Seems Apple doesn't give a public API for autocorrections,
So you should do this with some tricks and hacks.

This article should be useful.
http://blog.persistent.info/2013/10/programmatically-accepting-keyboard.html

Comment: This isn't a very clear article about how something like this could be implemented in code, do you have any idea about that? And would apple reject an app which used a method like the one above? Thanks!

Comment: probably yes, it will be rejected. the only thing you can do to integrate some 3rd party autocorrection library

Comment: Okay then, Thanks. Do you know of any such libraries?:P

Answer (score 0):

Copied From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651438/3322203)

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // Turn spell check on
    textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // Turn spell check off and clean up red squiggles.
    textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    NSString *currentText = textView.text;
    textView.text = @"";
    textView.text = currentText;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What difference does that make? Aren't you just disabling the autocorrect feature of the textfield?

Comment: no you can try it it will send 1 except NSTextAutoCorrectionNO that we use to disabled the autocorrection.